# quotient of planar groups

Tags: co.combinatorics

If G is an infinite planar group (it means that it has a generating subset C such that Cay (S, C) is a planar graph) and H is a normal subgroup of it, I would be very grateful if somebody helps me and tell me "is G/H a planar group?"

Comment: The usual terminology is that a group is planar if its _subgroup lattice_ is planar.

Comment: Thanks This is Meschke's definition of planar groups. You are righr! I should have remarked it. There are two definitions of planar groups. That is why I wrote the definition.  I need this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dihedral groups can be viewed as the set of all functions of the form $x\mapsto\pm x+c$ acting either on $\mathbb{Z}$ or on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The images of the infinite dihedral group are either finite dihedral groups. Taking as generators $x\mapsto x+1$ and $x\mapsto -x$ you get for the dihedral group of order $2n$ a planar Cayley graph consisting of two circles of length $n$.

Hence the infinite dihedral group is an example of an infinite non-abelian group, which has only planar images. I tried to find a more interesting example, but failed.

Comment: Thank you very very much I have the counter example that I need now. Again thanks so much to both of you

Answer (score 2):

With your definition, a free group is planar (since its Cayley graph is a tree), so if your conjecture were correct, then *every* finite generated group would be planar. This is  obviously false (though no counterexample leaps to mind just now; presumably $PSL(n, 5)$ should contain $K_5$s for some $n$).

Comment: Thanks so much! You are right again. I checked finite abelian groups and I infinite ones. But I completely forget the free groups. Do you know an infinite non-abelian planar group which has this property?

Comment: @khers you mean: is there an infinite non-abelian planar group such that every quotient is planar?

Comment: yes exactly Even now you helped me very much. Thanks again